# Error message in form validation below input type

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

i have a project in school, i am a beginner in codeigniter framework. Now i am using form validation library in my codeigniter. How can i make like this: (PER INPUT TYPE in my form) Input type and below is it's error message that come's from codeigniter form validation. Now here is my code where it duplicates all error message and will be posted every input type.

For example, if i leave Middle Name and First Name input types blank, my code will put error message each input type below the input types.

Here is my code:
VIEW:

```
<div class="modal fade large" id="admin_create_acct" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header  btn-success">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h3 class="modal-title">Create Account</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form class="form-horizontal" id="frm_create_user">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="userFName" class="control-label col-sm-4">First Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userFName" id="userFName" placeholder="First name">
                     <div class="msg"></div><!-- form-group -->
                  </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
                </div><!-- form-group -->
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="userMName" class="control-label col-sm-4">Middle Name:</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="userMName" id="userMName" placeholder="Middle name">
                    <div class="msg"></div><!-- form-group -->
                  </div><!-- col-sm-6 -->
                </div><!-- form-group -->
            </form><!-- form-horizontal -->
            </div><!-- modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" id="btn_reg" onclick="create_User()" class="btn btn-primary">Create Account</button>
```

Here is my controller where i set rules per input types:

```
public function reg_user(){

       $this->form_validation->set_rules('userFName', 'userFName', 'trim|required',
        array('required' => 'Error Message on First name ')
        );

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('userMName', 'userMName', 'trim|required',
        array('required' => 'Error Message on Middle Name')
        );

       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $result['type'] = 'error';
            $result['message'] = validation_errors();
        }else {
           $result['type'] = 'success';
           $result['message'] = 'Whooos..! Your Succes Message';   
        }

        echo json_encode($result);  
}
```

my ajax code:

```
function create_User() {
   $.ajax({
      url: siteurl+"admin_controls/reg_user",
      type: "POST",
      data: $("#frm_create_user").serialize(),
      dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(data) {
          if (data.type == "error") {
                        $('.msg').html(data.message);
                    }else{
                        // You can Sow this or Alert this
                        $('.msg').html(data.message);

                        alert('succcess fullyInserted')
                    }

                  $("#frm_create_user")[0].reset();
        }
   });
}
```

here is what happens:
[image]

Comment: You have to somehow tie every validation message to its input.

Comment: @u_mulder can you post some answer sir?

Comment: No, I can't( I'm not familiar with Codeigniter)

Comment: @u_mulder i am still a beginner of codeigniter that's why i am asking sir how to remove duplicate every textfield

Answer (score 1):

Following CI manual I propose the following.

You need to show each error message individually, that's why in `$result['message']` you need some structure like:

```
$result['message'] = [
    // fieldName => error text
    'userFName' => 'error text',
    'userMName' => 'another error text',
];
```

I suppose to use [`form_error`](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#form_error) function. So you need to check every field if it has error:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $result['type'] = 'error';

    // init message with empty array
    $result['message'] = [];

    if (!empty(form_error('userFName'))) {
        $result['message']['userFName'] = form_error('userFName');
    }

    if (!empty(form_error('userMName'))) {
        $result['message']['userMName'] = form_error('userMName');
    }
    // sure you can simplify this somehow
} else {
    $result['type'] = 'success';
    $result['message'] = 'Whooos..! Your Succes Message';   
}
```

Next we check response on a client:

```
if (data.type == "error") {
    // here we iterate over `data.message`
    $.each(data.message, function( key, value ) {
        // just for test
        console.log(key, value);

        // now we need to find element where to put error text
        // according to your current markup - 
        // error field is next to input with a certain id:
        $("#" + key).next().text( value );
        // As we have `key` as `userFName` then 
        // input with id `userFName` will be found
        // and error text will be put into a div next to it
    });
} else { /* do other stuff */ }
```

Of course, there can be other ways, I found this one.